# Help to understand proof of Glue Rule for continuous real functions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> **Theorem**:
>
> Let $f$ be defined on an open interval $I$ and let $a \in I$. If there are functions $g, h$ such that:
>
> 1. $f(x) = g(x)$, for $x \in I, x < a$ and $f(x) = h(x)$ for $x \in I, x > a$,
> 2. $f(a) = g(a) = h(a)$, and
> 3. $g$ and $h$ are continuous at $a$,
>
> then $f$ is also continuous at $a$.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> - We want to show that for each sequence $(x_n)$ in the domain of $f$ such that $x_n \rightarrow a$, we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a)$.
> - Since $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $I$ is an open interval, there is an integer $N$ such that $x_n \in I$, for $n \ge N$.
> - Then $(x_n)^\infty_N$ (the sequence $x_N, x_{N+1}, ...$) consists of two subsequences $(x_{m_k})$ and $(x_{n_k})$ defined by:
>
> $$x_{m_k} < a$$
> $$x_{n_k} \ge a$$
>
> for $k = 1, 2, ...$.
>
> - By conditions 1, 3 we have $g(x_{m_k}) \rightarrow g(a)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and $h(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow h(a)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.
> - Hence by conditions 1 and 2 we have $f(x_{m_k}) \rightarrow f(a)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and $f(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow f(a)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.
> - Since both subsequences of $(f(x_n))$ tend to $f(a)$, the theorem holds.

I have trouble understanding the definition of the sequence $(x_n)^\infty_N$. I

How would such a sequence look like? How I understand it, $(x_n)^\infty_N$ is a part of a sequence $(x_n)$ in the domain of $f$ AND in the open interval $I$. We picked $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \rightarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

But how can it be then that $(x_n)^\infty_N$ has a subsequence $x_{n_k} \ge a$? How does this sequence contain $a$ and numbers greater than $a$ if it's supposed to be tending to $a$?

I drew a graph of my understanding, but I actually can't wrap my head around how the sequence $(x_n)^\infty_N$ looks like.

[image]

Comment: 1. The subsequence $(x_{k})_{N}^{\infty}$ is sometimes called a _tail_; it's the result of "discarding" or "ignoring" the initial set of terms (up to $k = N-1$). Here, we discard enough terms that all the remaining terms are in $I$. 2. IIRC, you needn't get subsequences of the type indicated ($<a$ and $\geq a$) unless you allow a sequence to be finite. 3. If you can do this with a $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ argument it's perhaps a little cleaner.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thanks a lot for your reply, I follow 1., but not yet 2. Regarding 3. the course book I'm following insists on introducing this and other theorems based on this sequence based definition - in the next chapter epsilon/delta will come up. TBH I'm also not very happy with this and would prefer epsilon/delta straight away, but I'll follow along with the book at the moment.

Comment: Point 2. refers to the fact that a sequence converging to $a$ might have (say) only finitely many terms smaller than $a$ and infinitely many greater. Taking the terms smaller than $a$ therefore gives a finite sequence which many people (including me, in this context) would not consider a "sequence" because there's no "limit". :) <> As for 3. There are certain pedagogical advantages to using sequences (e.g., we can immediately recycle results about limits of sums, products, and quotients), but ... well, they're not for everyone. :)